# hidden td does not accept width in table

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii

I have one grid view which display data in table format. I have to make table header sticky. So using some js code, i have generated replica of table header. And i am using that replica to display as sticky header(when user scrolls this header will display).

Original grid is generated automatically (i am using Yii).

```css
table.items {
    background: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px #D0E3EF solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="items">
 <thead style="display: block;">
  <tr>
   <th id="property-grid-current_c0" style="width:46.1px !important;border-right:1px solid #000">Watch</th>
   <th class="" colspan="2" style="display: none;width:18.1px !important;border-right:1px solid #000" id="property-grid-current_c1">&nbsp;</th>
   <th class="" colspan="2" id="property-grid-current_c2" style="width:261px !important;border-right:1px solid #000">Property Name</th>
   <th id="property-grid-current_c3" style="width:86px !important;border-right:1px solid #000">SVP</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Now the problem is hidden td's width is not effecting in table width. So how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

try to `visibility` `hidden`;

```css
table.items {
    background: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px #D0E3EF solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="items">
 <thead style="display: block;">
  <tr>
   <th id="property-grid-current_c0" style="width:46.1px !important">Watch</th>
   <th class="" colspan="2" style="visibility: hidden;width:18.1px !important;" id="property-grid-current_c1">&nbsp;</th>
   <th class="" colspan="2" id="property-grid-current_c2" style="width:261px !important">Property Name</th>
   <th id="property-grid-current_c3" style="width:86px !important">SVP</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. Now the problem is bg color is not affecting for that column.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean

```
visibility: hidden;
```

`display: hidden` does not exists

if you need to keep the header background color then you should consider to let the cell visible and hide just his content, like this:

```
<th class="" colspan="2" style="width:18.1px !important;" id="property-grid-current_c1"><span style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</span></th>
```

Comment: sorry, that was typo

Comment: @DS9 well, with `visibility: hidden;` your issue should be solved, isn't it?

Comment: now the Problem is header color is not affecting for that column.

Comment: @DS9 if you need that, you should consider displaying table cell like others and just hide the content

Answer (score 0):

You can change like below

```
<th class="" colspan="2" style="display: none;width:18.1px !important;" id="property-grid-current_c1">&nbsp;</th>
```

To

```
<th class="" colspan="2" style="display: hidden;width:18.1px !important;" id="property-grid-current_c1">&nbsp;</th>
```

It work